# Ask to have questionable activity reviewed

Tags: support, flagging, best-practices

I have seen some similar questions answered by a certain same person. And when I post my answer, it immediately get voted down by that person before even  enough time for them to see it.

They may be gaming the system.

whom should I talk to, to take a look into it.

Comment: thanks you. ----

Comment: *...get voted down by that person...* Since votes are anonymous, I have to wonder how you've discerned that it was any one person?

Comment: Also, looking at your 6 most recent answers, I see only *one* downvote on any of them. Could you provide more evidence of the repeated nature of the downvotes?

Comment: @Kyle I suspect at a detailed account would be actively unhelpful here. Kamran should flag the relevant threads so that moderators can act if necessary and appropriate.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, I had bearely clicked the post button, that I saw it got down voted. And I know who because the said they did it. All should be viewable in their comments.

Answer (score 5):

Raise a custom moderator flag on one of the relevant questions, explain in as much detail as you can the behaviour you've observed, and then go away and leave those threads alone.

If you want more of a back-and-forth conversation with a moderator to explain the situation and ask for guidance, then ping a moderador on chat after you've raised your flag, and ask for help.